# Detect close tab/browser without message etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like doing in javascript (jQuery):

```
if (close tab || close window) {
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_form.php",
        data: dataString

        });
}
```

Is this possible without message if you want leave page etc?

Comment: but how defined close tab and close window? :)

Comment: Event is [beforeunload](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=onbeforeunload+jquery)

Comment: beforeunload show me alert with message. i have this without message

Comment: Hey I just wanted to warn you not to do anything mission critical there because you'll never be sure how the session was ended. The browser may have crashed, for instance, or the cat may have torn out the power cable. Although you're probably aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one useful event you can rely on for that reason, `onbeforeunload`.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.ajax({});
};
```

Unless you explicitly return `false` from that event, there is no message to the user. You might want to create a synchronised request anyway, because the browser will not wait for an asyncronous request to finish.